# Setting up the input on an RNN in Keras

Tags: input, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I had a specific question with setting up the input in Keras.

I understand that the sequence length refers to the window length of the longest sequence that you are looking to model with the rest being padded by 0's.

However, how do I set up something that is already in a time series array?

For example, right now I have an array that is 550k x 28. So there are 550k rows each with 28 columns (27 features and 1 target). Do I have to manually split the array into (550k- sequence length) different arrays and feed all of those to the network?

Assuming that I want to the first layer to be equivalent to the number of features per row, and looking at the past 50 rows, how do I size the input layer?

Is that simply input_size = (50,27), and again do I have to manually split the dataset up or would Keras automatically do that for me?

Comment: How many sequences do you have in that array?

Comment: The entire array is a sequence. So basically there are 550k time steps in that sequence, and at each time step i have 28 variables.

Comment: Ok :) -- And do you have only one sequence? Or there are more arrays?

Comment: Just one for now. I just want to get some sort of model up and running.

Comment: Ok, and a last question: what do you expect from the output? A sequence of targets with the same length 550k? Or a sequence with 1 target per each 50 steps? Or even a single target for the entire sequence?

Comment: A sequence of targets. So 550k-sequence length answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RNN inputs are like: `(NumberOfSequences, TimeSteps, ElementsPerStep)`

- Each sequence is a row in your input array. This is also called "batch size", number of examples, samples, etc.
- Time steps are the amount of steps for each sequence
- Elements per step is how much info you have in each step of a sequence

I'm assuming the 27 features are inputs and relate to `ElementsPerStep`, while the 1 target is the expected output having 1 output per step.
So I'm also assuming that your output is a sequence with also 550k steps.

**Shaping the array:**

Since you have only one sequence in the array, and this sequence has 550k steps, then you must reshape your array like this:

```
(1, 550000, 28) 
    #1 sequence
    #550000 steps per sequence    
    #28 data elements per step

#PS: this sequence is too long, if it creates memory problems to you, maybe it will be a good idea to use a `stateful=True` RNN, but I'm explaining the non stateful method first.
```

Now you must split this array for inputs and targets:

```
X_train = thisArray[:, :, :27] #inputs
Y_train = thisArray[:, :,  27] #targets
```

**Shaping the keras layers:**

Keras layers will ignore the batch size (number of sequences) when you define them, so you will use `input_shape=(550000,27)`.

Since your desired result is a sequence with same length, we will use `return_sequences=True`. (Else, you'd get only one result).

```
 LSTM(numberOfCells, input_shape=(550000,27), return_sequences=True)
```

This will output a shape of `(BatchSize, 550000, numberOfCells)`

You may use a single layer with 1 cell to achieve your output, or you could stack more layers, considering that the last one should have 1 cell to match the shape of your output. (If you're using only recurrent layers, of course)

**stateful = True:**

When you have sequences so long that your memory can't handle them well, you must define the layer with `stateful=True`.

In that case, you will have to divide `X_train` in smaller length sequences`*`. The system will understand that every new batch is a sequel of the previous batches.

Then you will need to define `batch_input_shape=(BatchSize,ReducedTimeSteps,Elements)`. In this case, the batch size should not be ignored like in the other case.

`*` Unfortunately I have no experience with `stateful=True`. I'm not sure about whether you must manually divide your array (less likely, I guess), or if the system automatically divides it internally (more likely).

---

#### The sliding window case:

In this case, what I often see is people dividing the input data like this:

From the 550k steps, get smaller arrays with 50 steps:

```
X = []

for i in range(550000-49):
    X.append(originalX[i:i+50]) #then take care of the 28th element

Y = #it seems you just exclude the first 49 ones from the original
```

Comment: Sorry I just looked over my previous comments and realized my minus sign may have been read as a hyphen. I meant to say (550k minus sequence lenght). So basically if I had a 30 sequence length window i would have 549,970 different sequences to turn through the model.

Comment: So.... how many steps should the layer walk forward in it's recurrency? 50 or 1? ---- Suppose you have elements from 1 to 31, will this give me two outputs? One considering 1 to 30 and the other considering 2 to 31?

Comment: I'm confusing myself now. 50 steps. Please ignore the 30 from above. So effectively from time step 50 i get one output (prediction), and for each time step from there until the end of the sequence I get 1 prediction for each step. So it's stepping forward by 1, each time, but looking back at the past 50 timesteps?  Or maybe I don't need to define how many steps to look back, as the RNN will do that itself?

Comment: I can think of an easy way: do exactly the same as in my answer, and discard the first 49 results. (But this will probably represent a window larger than 50 - The exact size is not possible to know). -- The hard way, which is what I often see in tutorials, involves separating your input array in smaller sequences, each with 50 steps.

Comment: I'm going to give the easy way a shot. But just for reference if I were to go the hard route and break into into smaller sequences each with 50 steps then that would mean I know had 549,950 batches?   Also how do I change the depth of the hidden state of the RNN?

Comment: 549951 batches, yes. So an input shape of `(549951,50,27)`. I don't know about the depth of the hidden state. I don't think there is one. It's just updated over and over.

Comment: I think there's a way to change that, but I'll do some more research.  Thanks so much for your help! Makes a ton more sense now.