# What should be the batch for Keras LSTM CNN to process image sequence

Tags: keras, lstm

I want to use image sequence to predict 1 output.

training data:

```
[(x_img1, y1), (x_img2, y2), ..., (x_img10, y10)]
```

Color image dimension:

```
(100, 120, 3)
```

Output dimention: (1)

Model implemented in Keras:

```
img_sequence_length = 3

 model = Sequential()
 model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode="same", activation=‘rely’, name='conv1'),
          input_shape=(img_sequence_length,
                       100,
                       120,
                       3)))
```

….

```
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, name='lstm_1'))
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, name='lstm_2'))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dense(1, name='output'))
```

The batch should be:

A)

```
[ [(x_img1, y1), (x_img2, y2), (x_img3, y3)], 
  [(x_img2, y2), (x_img3, y3), (x_img4, y4)],

…
]
```

Or

B)

```
[ [(x_img1, y1), (x_img2, y2), (x_img3, y3)], 
  [(x_img4, y4), (x_img5, y5), (x_img6, y6)],
…
]
```

Why?

Comment: What is `y` in that data?

Comment: Y is 1 dimension array. For example y = [0.45], or y = [9.45]. That's why model.add(Dense(1, name='output'))

Comment: Do you want one output per image? I thought it was one output for the sequence. So, is the sequence actually important for the results? I mean, does the previous image affect the result of the next image? Or are the images independent?

Comment: The image sequence does matter, but I am only interested in last output. For example, 3 consecutive images has 3 matching outputs. When creating batch (length = 3), I ignore 2 outputs for 2 images, only take 3rd Y. Also, last LSTM layer: return_sequences=False. NOT True. That's why output is 1 not 3. My another question: if I should create 3 outputs for another model (only outputs different from posted). Lets solve my batch question, as I am not sure which batch is right, or both are correct.

Comment: Is this 3 a fixed number? And do the outputs really "match" or they may be different? (I'm asking all these questions because it does affect how to organize your data). --- I couldn't understand what you mean with the LSTM part.

Comment: 3 is image sequence length. It can change to such as 10, depending on training result. Not sure which length work now. Sample: [(img1, [0.4]), (img2, [0.11]), (img3, [9.1]). Output is linear activation (no activate). LSTM: see model definition above. Model has 2 LSTM layers after many conv layers and flatten layer. My question: 2 kind batches. Not sure how LSTM remember previous images. Should I let batch to have 'previous' image? A) batch to 'remember' previous image; B) batch does not have previous image.

Comment: regarding sequence length. See:input_shape=(img_sequence_length,
                       100,
                       120,
                       3)). img_sequence_length can be changed. If 3 does not give me good result, I might try longer sequence length.

Answer (score 0):

This choice really depends on what you want to achieve. Understanding what your data is totally influences the decision. (Not only the shape and type of the data, but what it means and what you want from it. Is it a video? Many videos? Do I want the name of the character in a little segment of a video? Or to know the state of the plot continously along the video?)

**In option A:**

This option is used when all your images form a single long sequence and you want to predict the next element in the sequence by knowing a specific number of previous images.

Each group of 3 images in that batch is completely independent. 
The layer doesn't keep a memory between them, and the actual memory is length 3.

The simulation of a long sequence happens because you are repeating images in each batch, like a sliding window. But there is no connection or memory transfer from one group to another.

You use this if the sequence has any logical possibility of being predicted from 3 images.

> Imagine you have one long video, but you watch only three 3 seconds of it and try to deduce something from those 3 seconds. But, your memory is completely washed away before you watch another 3 seconds. When you watch this 3 new seconds, you will not be able to remember what you watched before and you will not be able to say you watched 4 seconds. All you learn will be confined in 3 second segments.

**In option B:**

In this option, each group of 3 images has absolutely no connection at all to the others. You can use this as if every group of 3 images were a different sequence (not belonging to a long sequence).

> Image you have lots of videos, and they talk about different things. One is Titanic, the other is the Avengers, and so on.

This batch may be used for a case similar to the one proposed in A, but your sliding window would have a step 3. This would make learning faster, but also make it less learning.

**Other options:**

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989610/setting-up-the-input-on-an-rnn-in-keras/45990154#45990154), its answer and the comments to have more ideas.

---

**Some hints on splitting the data:**

First, input and output data must be separate:

```
X = [item[0] for item in training_data]
Y = [item[1] for item in training_data]
```

Then you must separate the sequences properly. 
As you defined in the `input_shape`, X must follow the same shape.

```
X.shape must be (numberOfSequences, img_sequence_length, 100, 120, 3)
```

So if it's a list of images, you must make sure that every image is a numpy array (transform them if necessary), and that you will later convert X to numpy:

```
X = np.asarray(X_with_numpy_images)
```

And if you have only one Y for each sequence, you may have it shaped as:

```
Y.shape must be (numberOfSequences,1)
```

You probably mount it taking values in steps of 3:

```
Y = [Y[(i+1)*3 - 1] for i in range(numberOfSequences)]
```

---

Now it's important to understand if each sequence of 3 images is independent of the other sequences, or if you have just one huge sequence divided in small parts.

In case one, use `LSTM(..., stateful=False)`, in case two, use `LSTM(...,stateful=True)`

---

And you will also probably need to reshape the tensors properly in the transition from the convolutional layers to the LSTM layers, because LSTM will require inputs shaped as (NumberOfSequences, SequenceLength, Features)

A suggestion is to use reshape layers:

```
model.add(Reshape((img_sequence_length,100*120*3)))
#of course the last dimension may be different if you don't use `padding='same'` in the convolutions of if you use pooling.
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your detailed posting. Actually, I have no issue of coding. My main questions is if batch should consider 'remember previous image'. In A) 2nd input (2nd line of input) try to "remember previous image", which start from img2. B) 2nd input NOT try to "remember previous image", which start from img4, as I though LSTM layer already remember previous img2 and img3? Sorry for not not clearly stated at the beginning. I have not problem to create batch for A) and B). Just not sure which is good for training.

Comment: Each "sequence" in the structure I proposed will remember the results of previous images in the "same sequence". But one sequence has no influence on the memory of the others.

Comment: hi daniel, I got a lot of additional information from you answer. Thank you. I got your answer of Y. I am not able to figure out if you agree with A) or B) or none? It's still not clear to me.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you want to know what happens in each case or you already know what happens and want to decide what to pick?

Comment: You don't agree any of the batch format A) or B) I originally asked? If not, can you tell me what's wrong? I could not figure out your proposed batch generator will generate what kind of format, mainly X. In original sample, image X + output Y pair length is 10 (not independent). Sequence length is 3 for a defined model. You posted format of Y, I got it. But, what is structure of X? Can you post a sample with image length 10, sequence length 3? Thank you.

Comment: I need to add 'stateful=True', as I have huge sequence and divide them into small parts when generating batch. I am not sure batch A) or B) will give good result. At present, I am not sure. Also, I am not 100% sure what's your proposed batch. thank you very much.

Comment: Updated my answer. -- I'm not saying anything is wrong. I still don't understand what your data is, and what you want from it, in terms of meaning (not in terms of shape and type). I try to explain the idea better in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. Option A applicable to my problem (partially, as you said each bactch item of 3 images is independed of previous batch item of last 3 images. I think I would like to remember previous batch item as it's reasonable to my problem). Clarify my problem: it's long video with length of 10. each image correspoding to 1 output, and I am interested in 1 output (previous 2 does not matter). Y(i + 1) depends on Y(i); X_img(i + 1) depends on X_img(i). Time sequence length=3.  continue....

Comment: My original question regarding A) or B): important is 2nd item in the batch. A): 2nd batch item starting from x_img2. B): 2nd item starting from x_img4. If set 'stateful=False', batch structure already has 'memory' on in single batch item, but no 'memory' between 1st and 2nd batch item. I think A) is correct in this case, as 1st output is from x_img3, as 2nd output is from x_img4. If using B), 1st output is from x_img3, 2nd output is from x_img6. A GAP!!! If set 'stateful=True', NN will remember state between batch item 1 and item 2. It's nice to have for my problem. Like to hear comment.